# Tablesorter - Dedicate one table row for a sponsor? (make it first, unsortable, custom css)

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

is it possible to insert a row into tablesorter that would always appear first no matter how you sort it, and would have its own custom css settings for that one row?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's very simple - tablesorter won't sort anything within the `<thead>`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column Head 1</th><th>Column Head 2</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Unsortable  1</td><td>Unsortable  2</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- sortable rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As far as CSS goes, either give the "special" row a separate class, or use `thead tr:last-child`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! What? That's not enough? Oh fine... ;)

Some have solved problems like this by putting two tables on top of each other with zero margins. This is too much of a headache for me as sizing, creating custom triggers for sorting, etc, become a maintenance chore.

Another possible answer is to add your own parser, as [shown here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html). You can then define what gets sorted to the top and what gets sorted down inside the format method (which is used by the sorter), allowing you to even put several custom sorted rows at the top.

It's very simple! Check out the example and see.

The simplest answer, though, is to use the `thead` tag (as I see Tomalak just beat me to while I was typing this!)